# What is the http-equiv attribute? Why is it named that?

Tags: html

I have looked at the MDN Documentation, and it says:

> **http-equiv**
>
> "This enumerated attribute defines the pragma that can alter servers and user-agents behavior. The value of the pragma is defined using the content and can be one of the following"

But I'm still left wondering what its name means. Its name isn't as self-explanatory as other attributes' names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's the **equiv**alent of **HTTP** headers.

Comment: Oh that makes sense. Thanks for the answer! A smooth answer too.